# Ionic 3 - Desabilitar teclado em view específica

Tags: ionic3, teclado

Estou usando o aplicativo em um coletor de dados com teclado físico. O cliente pediu para desabilitar o teclado virtual nativo do Android em algumas telas apenas.

Instalei o Keyboard do ionic-native, outro do cordova e não consegui de forma alguma um resultado satisfatório. O que acontece é que os plugins oferecem apenas os methodos `close()` ou `hide()` e ao colocar nos eventos `click`, `tap` e `focus` causa um efeito visual tosco, onde o teclado aparece rapidamente e se oculta.

Creio que isto ocorra devido ao fato de não estar desabilitando o teclado virtual para esta view, e sim, pedindo para ocultar/fechar quando ele está para aparecer.

Portanto, a dúvida é a seguinte: por ser uma aplicação hibrida, é possível desabilitar de forma que nem apareça o teclado, mesmo que rapidamente (fração de segundos)? E caso seja possível, como proceder?

Desde já agradeço!